# How can I add all my groups to a different user in bash?

Tags: shell-script, users, group

I've got a user named `foo`. I'd like `foo` to have all the same group memberships that I do. I thought I was close, with this:

`sudo usermod -a -G $(id -Gn | tr " " ",") node4`

The `id` piped to `tr` is working fine, producing output like `abc,def,ghi,jkl` etc. The docs that I've found say that the way to add a user to multiple groups is `usermod -a -G ftp,admins,othergroup <username>`.

When I run `id` for the new user after running `sudo usermod`, the user is only a member of one group, but the `id -Gn` for me returns about 10 groups.

Is the sudo command what is goofing me up here?

edit: it seems like the issue here is that the groups are not actually in /etc/group, they are somehow populated from Active Directory.

Comment: if node4 is your new user's name, there is no reason your one-liner shouldn't work under normal conditions. If it is not working, you need to specify what you are getting as an error or less than desired outcome.

Comment: you can accomplish that with usermod

Comment: @MelBurslan updated my post

Comment: while logged into your own account, run this `Groups=$(id -Gn | tr " " ","); echo ${Groups}`. do you see all the groups separated by comma signs ?

Comment: yes; when i run `sudo usermod -a -G abc,xyz node4` then I check with `sudo id node4` I do not see the groups added to the user; this seems odd

Comment: is there a permission or something that would block me from being able to modify a user's group -- without showing an error?

Comment: when you are root, which what sudo is effectively doing for you, you have no restrictions, unless you are working with an extremely restricted system that I have no knowledge of. Coming back to my original question, did you run the command as I asked ? `Groups=$(id -Gn | tr " " ","); echo ${Groups}` ? And what was the output ? I am curious if creating a subshell with those paratheses, is causing a strange behavior on your system. I tested on my CentOS 6 box and it works.

Comment: What OS / Distro / Release are you working on by the way ?

Comment: I answered your question already: yes. The output was a comma separated list of about 12 groups. I'm on CentOS 7. I've got a support ticket in, we'll know shortly

Answer (score 0):

What you have works on my system.

```
    user:~$ groups test;
    test : test
    user:~$ groups
    user adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare davfs2 wireshark
    user:~$ sudo usermod -a -G $(id -Gn | tr " " ",") test
    user:~$ groups test
    test : test adm cdrom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin user sambashare davfs2 wireshark
```

Comment: well crap; there must be something about this system that is goofy; waiting on support ticket